# WPF Popup doesn't close even if I open new screen from menu

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a WPf popup inside Usercontrol which I open & closed by binding IsOpen property. Problem which I am facing is that popup doesn't close even if I open a new screen from menu using hotkey and its showing on top of new screen. I tried to set StaysOpen="False" but its not working.

Popup IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsPopupOpen, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PopupAnimation="Fade" HorizontalOffset="30" StaysOpen="False">

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some of your source code?

Comment: popup is part of the style template which opens when we hover the mouse on linklabel. now if I open a new screen by using hotkey, this popup appears on top of new screen.